# Solve the Cauchy problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $U(x,y)$  be the solution to the Cauchy problem:

$$ xU_x + U_y  = 1, U(x,0) = 2\ln(x) , x>1$$

Then $U(e,1) =$

1. $-1$
2. $0$
3. $1$
4. $e$

My work is as follows. Since,

$$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{1} = \frac{dU}{1},$$

we get $U - y = C_1$ and $U = \ln\frac{x}{C_2}$.

We have given that $U(x,0) = 2 \ln(x)$, so $C_1 = 2\ln(x)$.

Thus, $U(x,y) = y + 2 \ln(x)$ But my answer is $2$, where am I wrong?

Comment: $U(x,y)=-y+2 \ln x$.

Comment: why U(x,y) = -y +2 ln(x)

Comment: Following your method I  get $U-y=f(U-\ln x)$, and using the initial condition it is easy to determine $f$.

Comment: using the initial condition we get 2 $ln x$ = f(1), how to conclude that U(x,y) = $-y$ + 2$ln x$

Comment: Actually we get $2 \ln x-0=f(2 \ln x- \ln x)$.

Comment: Thank you for giving me your valuable time